# class cast exception while loading image from the url in android

Tags: java, android

I'm using dynamic table layout, in that there is image, and textview. The data is coming from an XML document. What I want is that in table the layout at runtime, I have to get the parsed image and textview. I am getting the textview correctly but not the image. I used the method `LoadImageFromWebOperations` for loading the image, but it gets a class cast exception and error like this:

```
org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$LimitedInputStream
```

What could be causing the exception?

*EDIT code from comment*

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String friend_image) { 
  try { 
         System.out.println("friend_image "+friend_image); 
         InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(friend_image).getContent(); 
         Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name"); 
          return d; 
         } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Exc at oadImageFromWebOperations "+e);
           return null;
       } 
 }
```

Comment: Some code needed to solve your issue.

Comment: private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String friend_image)
   {
          try
          {
           System.out.println("friend_image "+friend_image);
                  InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(friend_image).getContent();
                  Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                  return d;
          }
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
                  System.out.println("Exc at LoadImageFromWebOperations "+e);
                  return null;
          }
  }and

Comment: Loading an image from the internet tutorial: http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/imageview-with-loading-spinner-t49439.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this code; it may solve your problem:

```
   Bitmap bmImg;
   public Bitmap downloadFile(String fileUrl){
      URL myFileUrl =null;          
      try {
           myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
           HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
           conn.setDoInput(true);
           conn.connect();
           int length = conn.getContentLength();
           InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

           bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
           //imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
           return bmImg;
      } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Better error handling
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
      }
 }
```